# access vba find date not working for single digit days

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I am trying to copy data from an access database to an excel spread sheet

first i need to find the right column by searching for a date, this works fine for dates where the day has 2 digits ie 16/09/2017 but for dates with a single digit day 6/09/2017 it cannot find the date

in excel i tried to do a find with 6/09/2017 and it found it fine but it couldn't find 06/09/2017

my field in access shows as 6/09/2017 so i am not sure where the problem is, code i have tried below (all with the same result)

```
colNo = .Cells.Find(What:=Format(Me.RejectDate,dd/mm/yyyy), After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=(-4123), SearchOrder:=2, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=False).Column

colNo = .Cells.Find(What:=CDate(Me.RejectDate), After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=(-4123), SearchOrder:=2, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=False).Column

colNo = .Cells.Find(What:=Me.RejectDate, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=(-4123), SearchOrder:=2, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=False).Column
```

is the 0 being added automatically? if so why? and how do i stop it?
or is something else the problem?

Comment: DD/MM/YYYY is international format and is not Access standard which is MM/DD/YYYY. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html. Using dd in the Format function forces the placeholder 0 so it formats as 06, not 6. I am surprised the Format function works at all without the format mask in quote marks.

Comment: Result of Format function is a string, not a date value. I just re-read the question. Very odd. The formatted date should match to 06/09/2017, not 6/09/2017.

Comment: @June7 oh my bad it did have quotes when i ran it but i just rewrote it hastily from the CDate one to show what i had tried when i copied it into the question

Comment: Im in New Zealand which is outside of the U.S. so my regional setting is New Zealand and the default date format is dd/mm/yyyy, not sure if it effects this at all but im stating it just in case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution
i just check if a 0 is added from the format function and remove the 0 if it is added

```
dataDate = Format(Me.RejectDatetb, "dd/mm/yyyy")
If Left(dataDate, 1) = "0" Then
    dataDate = Right(dataDate, Len(dataDate) - 1)
End If
colNo = .Cells.Find(What:=dataDate, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=(-4123), SearchOrder:=2, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=False).Column
```